# Unlock xcode files?

Tags: xcode

A few days ago I had an issue with my mac so I took it to the Genius bar at a local Apple store.  They said the partitions failed on the hard drive and that it had to be reformatted.  I use a program to automatically back up the system to an external server, so I wasn't concerned about loosing anything.  They reformatted and I've been putting things back in place.

What I have not been able to figure out.. I have a number of Xcode projects that I need to work on but when I try to open them in Xcode I get this.

> The file "project.xcworkspace" could not be unlocked.
>   Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it. Try modifying the permissions of the file in the Finder or Terminal.

I tried unlocking the project, the main folder, and the p.list file in finder and making sure that I had read/write access but I'm still getting the error.

When they reformatted the computer it did erase all of the keys and certificates I've been looking but I don't think the software backs up the credentials on the computer so I don't think I can access the old certificates and keys.

Has anyone run into this before?  How do I unlock the file?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Remember the Project isn't just a standalone "`.xcodeproj`" file but it's actually a folder that contains a number of hidden items.

So when applying permissions, make certain to apply permissions to *every* item in your project folder.

You can do this via the "Apply Permissions to Enclosed Items" popdown menu (available in the "Get Info" window), which looks like this:

[image: Apply Permissions to Enclosed Items]

Comment: "Apply to enclosed items" doesn't show up for me. Do you know why? I'm on OSX Sierra and Xcode 8.

Comment: If you can not select the "Apply to enclosed items" Make sure the padlock to the right of it is unlocked. If it is locked click it, and enter your password. Then the "Apply to enclosed items" will become selectable. ![illustrative image][1111] [1111]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2ota.png

Comment: If it doesn't you will have to go through the folder in finder and apply the permissions individually. It used to show up for me but currently for whatever reason doesn't. I just get the option to [Revert changes].

Comment: I don't know but because of some reasons it is not working for me.

Comment: Try going to the parent directory and checking there to see if it works.

Comment: Unable to see Apply to enclosed items button in this above screen after click on the lock to unlock

Comment: Eureka! Worked for me... Applying to enclosed items did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work at all. Even if I allow read/write for all the error persists but with message "can't unlock for unknown reason"

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is here using `Ionic Cordova` with the same issue, Michael's answer works but you must go to the parent directory which is the `ios folder` and the `Apply to enclosed items` will show up there.

Comment: Yes, Im using Ionic Cordova, I tried the solution but it says "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission."

Answer (score 3):

In my case (react native) was a problem with node_modules. I just remove it and made `yarn install`. Probably, they were installed with `sudo` so xcode hasn't permissions.

Comment: Awesome! That's was my issue too. Thank you