# Xcode locked editing

Tags: ios, xcode

I cloned a Xcode project to a new local machine, and it says that I don't have the permission to write or edit:

[image]

I figure that it must have to do with ownership and write permission and found this post [How to unlock xcode file to make edits from different computers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559542/how-to-unlock-xcode-file-to-make-edits-from-different-computers/9561906#9561906)

[image]
It still shows the red color text, any thoughts?

Comment: I see that you have `Pods`. I think you should open `.xcworkspace` file instead of `.xcodeproj` file

Comment: Thats what I did

Comment: Whenever i open xworkspace it will show that red error

Comment: Did you try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182676/unlock-xcode-files ?

Comment: Tried this method as well. @trungduc

Comment: is there any error displayed? Can you show it?

Comment: Theres no error I just can't edit the file

Comment: Please check again and make sure `NewCo.xcodeproj` exists in your project folder.

Comment: it does exist in my project folder